# EROR: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

Tags: apexrest, blob, character-encoding

We have a custom REST api that throws an error when ever we have a diacritic character as part of the JSON request.  For example if the character "é" is anywhere in the JSON it errors when we convert to string.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    @HttpPost
    global static String fetcheRAMmsg()
        {
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

            Map<String,String> eramFields = new Map<String,String>();
            String ackId;
            String errorMsg='None';
            system.debug('%%% - About to Parse the JSON: ' );
            system.debug('%%% - Headers from eRAM: '+req.headers);
            system.debug('%%% - About to Convert to String' );
            system.debug('%%% - JSON from eRAM: '+req.requestBody.toString());
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(req.requestBody.toString());
```

It fails at the `.tostring()` command.

It works fine if there are no diacritic charcters in it.  How do I check convert the BLOB to a string?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can't convert "BINARY" data into a String. A String only supports valid UTF-8 strings. Use EncodingUtil.Base64Encode if you need the binary data in a string you can work with.

```
String requestBodyResp = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(req.requestBody);
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(requestBodyResp);
```

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation rather than just a code dump.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
System.debug(Blob.valueOf('abcéééxyz').toString());
```

runs fine.

Suggest you examine the exact bytes that are sent to your end point.